# IFS Function is throwing 'Parse Error' and 'N/A No Match' when used with SUM [Google Sheets]

Tags: google-sheets

The desired end result is simply A1 > A2 + 10 = ▲

The line I've tried throws Parse Error:

(Even though when I highlight "(SUM(A3,10)" in the line it reads the correct sum value in the popup box)

`=IFS(A1>(SUM(A3,10), "▲")`

So I made a new cell (A3) and did the SUM Function separate:

`=SUM(A2,10)`

But when I run this line to draw from A3 it says "#N/A: Error No Match":

`=IFS(A1>A3, "▲")`

I can't figure out what's going on. IFS seems to want to reject SUM entirely even though SUM is working just fine. I even tried to run it with INT to no avail:

`=INT(SUM(A2,10))`

Answer (score 1):

=IFS(A1> `(` SUM(A3,10), "▲")

You put an extra parenthesis and it shouldn't have been there :)

Try:

```
=IF(A1>SUM(A3,10), "▲",)
```

Comment: (Nvmd my last message, I'm dumb and messed something up) Thank you! It worked!

How could it be added to this line?

``` =IFS(IMPORTRANGE("URL1","D6")>(IMPORTRANGE("URL1","H5")), CONCAT("▲",IMPORTRANGE("URL1","D6") )) ```

Comment: can you tell us what that url is? is it accessible?